# Inequality concerning sides of a triangle

Tags: inequality

I am trying to prove the following inequality: take $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^N\setminus\{0\}$ with $|x|\le |y|$ then $$\frac{1}{4}|x-y|\le |t x+(1-t)y|,\ \forall\ t\in [0,1/4].$$

I could prove some particular cases of it, like for example, the case where $y=kx$, however, the general case  is giving me some work. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=y-x$. The assumption $|x|\leq |y|$ becomes
$|y-z|\leq|y|$ or equivalently
$ |z|^2\leq 2<z,y> $.
Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we conclude that $|z|^2\leq 2|z||y|$ and consequently
$|y|\geq \frac{1}{2}|z|$.
Now, since $0\leq t\leq \frac{1}{4}$ then
$$
|tx+(1-t)y|=|y-tz|\geq |y|-t|z|\geq\left(\frac{1}{2}-t\right)|z|\geq \frac{1}{4}|z|
$$
which is the desired inequality.$\qquad\square$